# Alternate of using "delivery callback"

Tags: 8, routes, hooks

```
$items['mymodule/%user'] = array(
  'title' => 'My Module',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'delivery callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
);
```

Above code is from D7, I've used "`mymodule_ajax_callback`" as my "`delivery callback`" in D8 but I'm unable to find a way.

Tried finding solution here [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes) but I'm unable to get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for responses. For example, in a controller, you can return a renderable array, a [Symfony Response object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#response), or specific responses (AjaxResponse, JsonResponse) to respond to the request.

For example, [AjaxResponse in the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Ajax!AjaxResponse.php/class/AjaxResponse/8.2.x), and here is an example of a controller responding with it:

https://www.mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8